# JQuery hover with multiple ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to see if the working code below can be written more elegantly. I am assuming there is a way to parse out the "r" and "h" to condense it down into a function. Any help is much appreciated for learning purposes. There are no parent/sibling relationships in the ID's.

```
    $('#r1_1').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h1_1').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r1_2').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h1_2').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r1_3').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h1_3').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r1_4').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h1_4').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r1_5').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h1_5').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r2_1').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h2_1').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r2_2').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h2_2').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r2_3').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h2_3').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r2_4').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h2_4').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r2_5').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h2_5').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r3_1').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h3_1').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r3_2').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h3_2').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r3_3').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h3_3').toggleClass('vis');
    });
    $('#r3_4').hoverIntent(function(){
        $('#h3_4').toggleClass('vis');
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ids #r, let's include in the element the attribute data-something to differentiate the elements that must have the behavior setted by the function. Using a div, for instance:

```
<div data-something="1_1"></div>
<div data-something="2_2"></div>
```

We won't need the ids with #r anymore. Considering that you already have the elements #h* we just need to put the id number inside data-something of the corresponding element, so that the function can use it:

```
$("div[data-something]").hoverIntent(function() {
    var idNumber = $(this).data("something");
    $('#h' + idNumber).toggleClass('vis');
});
```

Now, you just need to use the data-something attribute.

Comment: ha ! i see we had the same idea at the same time :D

Comment: Thanks very much! Worked beautifully. And I learned a great deal from it.

Answer (score 1):

A basic function for running it could be

```
function hi(n1, n2) {
   var r = '#r'+n1+'_'+n2;
   var h = '#h'+n1+'_'+n2;
   $(r).hoverIntent(function() {
      $(h).toggleClass('vis');
   });
}
```

However, it's possible to trim this down more by creating an array, and storing both `r`, and `h` in it. The array would look something like this: `var arr = ["#r"+n1+"_"+n2, "#h"+n1+"_"+n2];`, and then instead of inserting `r` and `h` into the `hoverIntent` function, you would use `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`. If they are all meant to be run at once, you could run a nested `for` loop so that `r1_ - r3_` would be created, and then the secondary numbers would be populated.

Comment: Thank you Andrew - In the above basic function, how do I grab the unique values of n1 and n2?

Comment: @user2440204 n1 and n2 would be entered in as numbers. So for your first example, you would execute it as `hi(1, 1)`. If you need those numbers back, you could either add them as index two and three in the array, or you could return a different array with those two numbers in it.

Comment: Thanks again. I am having difficulty coding what you are describing, so I guess this goes beyond my skill level right now. I will do some more studying and research.

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
$('.hover_intent').hoverIntent(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr( 'id' ); 
     var selector = '#' + id.replace( 'r', 'h' );
     $( selector ).toggleClass('vis');
});
```

The only inconvenients i see are :

- you need to add a `hover_intent` css class or your `rx_y` elements. This can be avoided with a regex selector like `$('[id^=r]')` (which means: *select all elements whose id starts with an 'r'*), but you should then use a more verbose id to avoid selecting everything that starts with an 'r'...
- selecting `$(this)` every time the event occurs can be bad performance-wise, especially if you have a lot of elements or if the event occurs a lot of times per second

Another option is to use a data attribute on your element :

```
<span class="hover_intent" data-target="#h1_1">Foo</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.hover_intent').hoverIntent( function(){
    $( $(this).data('target') ).toggleClass('vis') );
  });
</script>
```